# double precision lost when parsing csv file in C

Tags: c, types, scanf

I'm trying to read in a file in c with the following format:

```
6.43706064058,4.15417249035
3.43706064058,1.15417249035
...
```

I'm able to parse out the two doubles, but when I print out what I've parsed, I notice that I only get up to 6 decimal places. Here is my code:

```
long double d1;
long double d2;
fscanf(file, "%Lf,%Lf", &d1, &d2);
printf("x:%Lf, y:%Lf", d1, d2);
```

Output:

```
x:6.437061, y:4.154172
...
```

Where am I losing the precision? Is it possible that its being read in correctly, but my printf statement isn't showing all the precision?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible that its being read in correctly, but my printf statement isn't showing all the precision?

That's exactly what's happening.  From the [`printf(3)` man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/printf/):

> ... the number of digits after the
>                decimal-point character is equal to the precision specification.
>                If the precision is missing, it is taken as 6 ...

Tell `printf` to show more precision by changing your format string:

```
 printf("x:%.11Lf, y:%.11Lf", d1, d2);
```

Answer (score 2):

The default `%f` format only prints 6 places after the decimal point, which gives you much less precision than the actual floating point value (unless the exponent is large) and possibly no precision at all (if the exponent is more than slightly negative). Unless you know all your values are bounded away from zero (e.g. all greater than 1), you really need to use the `%g` format (which can switch to exponential notation as needed) or the `%e` format (which always uses exponential notation) to print floating point values in a way that preserves their precision.

You also need to use sufficiently many decimal places. For IEEE double precision, 17 decimal places is sufficient, so `%.17g` would be the preferred format. For `long double`, it depends on the type used on your particular implementation. Thankfully, C offers a macro, `DECIMAL_DIG`, that gives you exactly the number of places you need. So you would use:

```
printf("%.*Lg", DECIMAL_DIG, x);
```

or similar. Note that this will print more places than were originally present in your input file. If you know your input always has a particular number of places, you could perhaps just hard-code that instead of using `DECIMAL_DIG` to get a more uniform output.

Comment: Indeed, I meant to write `%.*Lg`; I don't know why I slipped and wrote `f`. It's fixed now. If you'll notice, your comment is repeating the content of the beginning of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not as far with the precision as you'd like to be is because the level of the spacing in the number is not enough. In the first number, 6.43706064058, you have 13 numbers, including the decimal, so you'd put

```
    printf("x:%13Lf, y:%Lf", d1, d2);
```

allowing 13 spaces for the x:

for the second number, 4.15417249035, you have 13 also, so for that, you'd put

```
    printf("x:%13Lf, y:13%Lf", d1, d2);
```

and that will print:

```
    x:6.43706064058, y:4.15417249035
```

you must allow room for all of the spaces within the number when doing the printf function.
Hope that helped!

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Did you test your suggestion?

Comment: no I did not, try this: instead of having a long double, just use double itself. the double data type has a big range of numbers as it is, and then just use printf("x:%13f", y:%13f", d1, d2); and that should help.

Comment: `y:13%Lf` should be `y:%13Lf`. However, I can't understand why you suggest to use `double` instead of `long double` in this case.